# Riemann Curvature tensor for surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a regular surface on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am trying to express the Riemann's curvature tensor:
$$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$
respect $R(\vec x_i,\vec x_j)\vec x_k$. It is easy to show:
$$R(X,Y)Z=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n\Big(\nabla_{X^i\vec x_i}\nabla_{Y^j\vec x_j}Z^k\vec x_k-\nabla_{Y^j\vec x_j}\nabla_{X^i\vec x_i}Z^k\vec x_k\Big)-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$
What I can do with:
$$\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z\ ?$$
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to write the lie bracket of two vector fields in local coordinate?

Comment: are your basis vectors $\vec{x_i}$ holonomic?